# Chromedriver Version 119.0.6045.106 for Windows 64 bit

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, version

Ever since my chrome updated to 119.0.6045.106, I can't seem to find the correspond version anywhere.
For some reason, the official site have version 220 and above:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

I can't update to Chrome either since it's in my office system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Link for version 119:
(https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)